# Is there a way to change the "current buffer"--the one that gets defined when I use "n" and "N"?

Tags: buffers, navigation

Once in a while I do work on a large number of files (i.e. today it was about 1,700) using a command such as:

```
gvim `find . -name *.cpp`
```

and I use the "n" (no changes) or "wn" (made a change) to go through all my files.

Once in a while I notice I missed something and would like to restart at a certain position. Is there a way to reset that buffer position? I found that I could use a `<count>:n` or `<count>:N` but that's not as practical as specifying that this or that specific buffer should now be the one (i.e. I have to do the math...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `:n` you are going through the argument list. You can use `:args` to see where you are in the current argument list. You can use `:first` to start at the beginning and use `:last` to go to the last argument. You can also use `:previous` to go to the previous argument. To add files to the argument list you can use the `:argadd` and `argedit` command. And finally if you want to be at a specific argument, use `:Nargu` command (e.g. to edit the third file from your argument list, use `:3argu`.

Note, there is also the bufferlist, which is independent of the argument list. You can move through the buffer list using `:bnext` and similar commands.

Read the detail about it at [:h arglist](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#arglist) and [:h 07.2](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_07.txt.html#07.2)

Comment: Very cool! I've also been wondering about an inter-buffer next/previous capability.